# What happens when you reach the maximum streak?

Tags: draw-something

Apparently Draw Something has a maximum streak of 99 (which will be raised to 999 in a future update). What happens when you reach the maximum streak? Does that game end, does it reset to 0, or just remain at 99?

I'm up to 95 with one of my drawing partners so I'm wondering if it's worth us not playing until the update hits.

Comment: Be aware that the correct number always appears in the stats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to the update when you hit Turn 99, the counter would remain at 99 until a word was not guessed.

It would still do the animation between turns (when the counter would normally update), but the number would remain 99.

**EDIT:** As of the April 18th update, the limit has been removed and game count past 99 appears correctly. No idea what happens past 999 though.

Comment: That's correct. And it's really annoying because I'd be up to about 200 with some players... if it could go higher....

Comment: Hey Flutter, I updated your answer to reflect the latest update.

Answer (score 2):

Our score will not go above 999. The score has been stuck on 999 for several plays on draw something.